# Dynamic type check matching type parameters

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

I wish to implement a method with the following signature:

```
<T> void function(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> consumer)
```

This function takes an `Object obj` (supplied elsewhere), uses `clazz.cast(obj)` to cast it to `T`, and then invokes `consumer` with it. (Basically, it is a guard for `consumer`.)

This works more or less fine, I can write

```
Consumer<String> c = ...;
function(String.class, c);
```

Unfortunately, the following code does not work:

```
Consumer<List<String>> c = ...;
function(List.class, c);
```

This is because `List.class` has type `Class<List>`, not class `Class<List<String>>`.
I can change the type of `c` to `Consumer<List>`, but that would be incompatible with my code in other places (and raw types are not nice anyway).

Is there some way to (a) invoke `function` in a way that typechecks or (b) change the type signature of `function` in a way that makes this pattern work?

**Notes:**

- I wish to retain as much compile and runtime type safety as possible. So, `function(Class<?> clazz, Consumer<T> consumer)` would not be acceptable because the user can easily provide the wrong `clazz`. And invoking as `function((Class<List<String>>)List.class, c)` is also not acceptable because I could accidentally cast it as `function((Class<Integer>)List.class, c)` and
  this wrong cast would not even be caught at runtime. If there was a function that allows to cast `Class<C<T>>` to `Class<C<U>>` but not to `Class<D>`, that would be cool, but I don't see that without higher-order types.
- I am aware that the type casts will not be able to check at runtime that we have a `List<String>` and not a `List<Integer>`. That's OK. (Well, it's not, but I assume it's the best
  we can expect in a JVM language.)
- All being the same, I prefer solutions that make the invocation of `function` simple (possible making `function` more complex) because `function` is defined in my library and used by the user of that library.
- For the curious, the actual code where I have this problem is [here](https://github.com/dominique-unruh/java-patterns/blob/aa651ed9c0ee1bc4f779464829acd10bf9ef8b5a/src/main/java/de/unruh/javapatterns/Patterns.java#L522), `Instance` is `function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you want with just a `Class<T>` argument. You need a [*super type token*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-super-type-tokens) instead.

As explained in the linked article, this is how you might implement such functionality:

```
public abstract class TypeToken<T> {
 
    private final Type type;
 
    public TypeToken() {
        Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        type = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
 
    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

In Java, you cannot grab info about generic type variables of instances, however you can get some info about the generic type variables of super types. Note that the `TypeToken` class is abstract. This is how you should use it in your example:

```
<T> void function(TypeToken<T> token, Consumer<T> consumer)

Consumer<List<String>> c = ...;

function(new TypeToken<List<String>>() { }, c);
```

This means that you are passing a subclass of `TypeToken` to your function.

Finally, inside `function`, you can extract a `Class` instance and type cast an object as follows:

```
Class<T> clazz;
if (type instanceof ParameterizedType)
  clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType();
else if (typeU instanceof Class)
  clazz = (Class<T>) type;
else
  throw new RuntimeException("Error handling omitted");
T t = clazz.cast(obj);
```

Comment: Nice solution, even thought the "new" and "{}" makes syntax a bit unwieldy. A slight optimization: by defining `function` as a class instead of a method (`abstract class function<T>` with constructor `function(Consumer<T>)`), we have the somewhat more compact invocation: `new function<T>(c){}` instead of `function(new TypeToken<T>{},c)`.

Comment: One misuse of a `TypeTag` is to inherit from a subclass of `TypeTag`. (Then `getGenericSuperclass` would give the wrong `Type`.) To avoid this, we can add an extra check in the constructor: `if (getClass().getSuperclass() != TypeTag.class) throw ...`. I'm not 100% sure the != semantics are correct here, though. Can the same class have two different Class objects?

Comment: `tryCast` as described does not work if `T` is itself a parameterized type, because then `type` is not an instance of `Class`. So we need to additionally check whether `type instanceOf ParametrizedType`, and if so, use `type.getRawType()` to get the actual `Class` instance.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh I agree to your comments and fixes. Feel free to edit my answer, or let me know if you need me to edit it

Comment: A working implementation of this idea is here: https://github.com/dominique-unruh/java-patterns/blob/f037dfb9c35704d762c03f02d03a25698adc7def/src/main/java/de/unruh/javapatterns/Patterns.java#L558 (`Instance` is `function`).

Comment: sure, I didn't mean to say that the answer was lacking something, just adding some extra insights that I found based on your helpful answer and that I think can be useful for others. I will add how to cast using the type tag.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh Sure, maybe my previous comment was too harsh, so I deleted it. But it was because I didn't find the correct words :) Your question is very good and can help others. Yes! It would be very nice if you could post your solution to cast with the type token (or part of it) in the question

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh Thanks for the edit! That greatly improves my answer!

Comment: 1+. turns out I was playing with the [same thing a while ago](https://github.com/wind57/0xMapper/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/er/mapper/Utils.java#L217) and there are more types that can come up from a `Type`

Comment: Hi @Eugene! Nice to know about you :) Yes, generics are enough nightmare to use, imagine their reflection counterpart...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to achieve the degree of type safety you aim at.

Let's distinguish compile time and run time.

### Compile Time

At compile time, the compiler checks whether the type of `clazz` matches the `consumer`'s type parameter `T`. But that doesn't work well with types T that themselves have generics type parameters, e.g. `List<String>`, as there is no `List<String>.class` syntax in Java. So, here the best you can do is cast the `List.class` to `Class<List<String>>`.

The object `obj` that gets operated upon in your `function` isn't visible in the method's signature, so at compile time there's no chance to check whether its type matches the `consumer`.

There's nothing stopping you from calling `function(String.class, stringConsumer)` and having an `Integer` object. There's no chance the compiler will detect that mistake.

### Run Time

At run time, there is no generics information. That concept is called "type erasure". So, something that at compile time appears as a `List<String>`, at runtime is just a `List`.

As at compile time, the `obj` is not visible at the `function` invocation, you moved the type check to run time, using the `Class.cast()` method.

If at compile time your `obj` is a `List<String>`, a `List<Integer>`, or a `List<Whatever>`, at run time it's just a raw `List` without parameters, and the class you are checking against also is just the raw `List.class`, without any type parameters. The `cast()` method will accept all these different lists.

So, at run time there's no way to reject a `List<Integer>` from entering a consumer expecting a `List<String>`. You'll probably get a `ClassCastException` later when the consumer accesses the list elements.

### Summary

If you want to guard against mismatch of parameterized types, you can only do so at compile time, and to make that possible you have to bring object and consumer into the same syntactic context, probably meaning a big refactoring.

At run time, you can only guard against mismatch of raw types. If you want to do that, it forces you to use some ugly syntax in case of parameterized types (casting the class object to a parameterized class type), just to satisfy the compiler.

Personally, I'd give up the guarding idea.

- It doesn't help at compile time (it only checks whether you were able to pass a `clazz` matching the `consumer` into `function`, not whether the actual object matches).
- It can check for some error cases at run time. But in cases like `List<String>`, it still can't protect you from getting a `ClassCastException` later, thrown by the consumer. And that's what happens without your guard as well, just in more cases.

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding. According to my requirements (second bullet in notes), I am fine with (runtime) checking only the `List` part, not the `List<String>` part. Which is easy to implement (given `List.class`). But typing the function correctly so that I can pass a `Consumer<List<String>>` without compiler error is the difficult part (even if I don't care about safety of the `String` part). The naive solution only allows me to pass `Consumer<List>`. (That's because `List.class` has type `Class<List>`; there is no possibility to get a `Class<List<String>>` without casting.